# Trying to create a MySQL Procedure that collates any table record into a string

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, foreach, string-parsing

I'm very new to MySQL procedures, but I'm in need of one that will, given a table's name and a record Id, produce a string representation of the fields and data and return it.

I want it to work on every / any table in the database given only the table's name and the record Id to parse, so I can't hardcode the fields ahead of time. The output I'm looking for needs to be in the following form:

```
{{tableName:recordId|'field1Name'="field1Data";'field2Name'="field2Data"...;}}
```

I've been trying to figure out how to do this, but have no idea how to dereference the field names + data from a variable populated by an appropriate SELECT statement, and *really* no idea of how to build the requisite string from all of that data. I looked at the `ForEach()` statement, but don't know how to cause it to iterate through each field of a record and recall both the field names and the requisite data.

Every record in every table that will be dereferenced through this procedure has a field called "id" that's defined as `BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` and is set as the `PRIMARY KEY` on each of the said tables.

Can someone give me some pointers on how to put this thing together?

I've only got this much, so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `CompileRecord`(
IN  tableName            VARCHAR(64),
    targetRecordId       BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED,
OUT compiledData         TEXT
)
BEGIN
    SET oldData = SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE `id`=targetRecordId LIMIT 1;
    SET compiledData = CONCAT("{{",tableName,":",targetRecordId,"|");
    IF NOT oldData IS NULL THEN
        /* 
            no idea what to do here? in PHP might look like..
            foreach ($oldData as $field => $data)
                $compiledData .= "'".$field."'=\"".$data."\";";
            ??
        */
    ENDIF
    SET compiledData = CONCAT (compiledData,"}}");
END
```

Comment: The more I keep working at this, the more wrong I find in my code above, and the less likely it seems that this is even possible... 

Comment: SET oldData = you will get error since it can hold only one variable, if the table has more than one column it happens, so specify the column name or take count(*). Since the column in where `id` assuming it as PK "limit 1" is useless because it will return only one row.

Comment: As I commented, there are many problems / errors with the attempt I posted above. Given that the intent of the function was to process any one of a few dozen tables, all with different schemas, it would be impractical to code the field(s) manually (if not outright impossible).

As I said, given what I've learned, I don't think accomplishing what I wanted to do with this procedure is possible given the significant limitations of the processing engine.